# как сделать post на JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, post

1.Вызов ajax по URL-адресу: /echo/html/

2.Отправить 1 параметр с ключом 'html'

3.В качестве значения значение источника атрибут напечатать результат внутри DIV с помощью «result3»

```
<div class="test">
      <div>
          <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/2.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/6.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/3.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/4.png" alt="">
      </div>
    <div id="test2">
    <div>
        <img src="img/5.png">
</div>
<button id="btntest2">Go</button>

</div>
<div id="test3">
    <div id="result3"></div>
    <button id="btntest3">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#result3").load("/echo/html", { html: 'xxx'})`

Comment: спасибо большое